# Grep does not work

Tags: macos, terminal, grep

I am experiencing a strange behaviour with GREP on my mac terminal.

I have a list of IDs to search for in another file. My IDs are in `cluster_1.txt`. I want to fetch all these IDs from another file `1.2FoldRegulatedIn6Samples_normFC_no102.txt`

The IDs file and the target file contains an ID `"CDK17"`

```
grep CDK17 cluster_1.txt 

grep CDK17 1.2FoldRegulatedIn6Samples_normFC_no102.txt
```

Both the above commands tells me that they contains the ID. But when I do

```
 grep -w -F -f cluster_1.txt 1.2FoldRegulatedIn6Samples_normFC_no102.txt | grep "CDK17"
```

I don't get any results. Its very strange and I do not know why it would happen.

Comment: you want cat, not grep, before pipe

Comment: I am just checking if the grep command is puling out the ID CDK17 from the file. 1.2FoldRegulatedIn6Samples_normFC_no102.txt

Comment: You need to run `grep -w -F "CDK17" cluster_1.txt` and `grep -w -F "CDK17" 1.2FoldRegulatedIn6Samples_normFC_no102.txt` first for the test to be fair since you are currently using different options.